# Keep UILabel centered in UIView when character lengths change. iOS, Objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` that I have centered in the middle of the screen. The number values can at most contain three digits. for example 500.

My problem is that when the values change it makes the `UILabel` position itself off center.

In the below images you will see that when the values equal 3 digits the slider labels look centered and when the slider label values are say 12 then the label looks off centre.

I need the `UILabel` to adjust itself to be centered always in the `UIView`.

I have tried the code below to add to my `UILabel` with no luck.

[image]
[image]

```
self.myCircleSliderValueLabel.font = sliderValueFont;
self.myCircleSliderValueLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:103/255.0 green:187/255.0 blue:230/255.0 alpha:1.0];;
self.myCircleSliderValueLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
self.myCircleSliderValueLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
self.myCircleSliderValueLabel.text = @"400";
[self.myCircleSlider addSubview:self.myCircleSliderValueLabel];

self.myCircleSliderValueLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Comment: Set your autolayout constraints to centre the label and then call sizeToFit when you update the text. The label should then centre itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest and fastest way is to set fixed width for your `myCircleSliderValueLabel` (to accommodate all three digits) and set `textAlignment` property to `NSTextAlignmentCenter`.

Edited:

Or you can use auto layout. Something like this ...

```
NSLayoutConstraint *con = [NSLayoutConstraint
  constrainWithItem:self.myCircleSliderValueLabel
  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX             // It says that X center
  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual                // Should equal
  toItem:self.myCircleSliderValueLabel.superview // To your label superview's...
  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX             // ... X center
  multiplier:1.0
  constant:0.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter?

Comment: this is more like a comment than an answer